How to join the results of one table with another table which does not exist in first table in SQL query?
I have two sample tables like below.
Table A



Date
StageID
ProductName
Change




5/10/24
123
PN1
1


5/10/24
153
PN2
2


5/10/24
153
PN1
2



Table B



Date
BatchID
ProductName




5/10/24
1
PN1


5/10/24
1
PN2


5/10/24
1
PN3


5/10/24
2
PN1


5/10/24
2
PN2



Table 3



Date
StageID
BatchID
StageName




5/10/24
127
1
Import


5/10/24
123
1
Export


5/10/24
155
2
Import


5/10/24
153
2
Export



I need to get all the result set from table A with changes 1 and 2 along with table B results (rest of product names) not in table A as change 0 for each batch ID
Desired Result from table A and B as below



Date
BatchID
ProductName
Change




5/10/24
1
PN1
1


5/10/24
1
PN2
2


5/10/24
2
PN1
2


5/10/24
1
PN3
0


5/10/24
2
PN2
0



I have written a query to:
select all from table A with change 1 or 2 along with additional join with 3rd table
Union
the result from table B as change 0 (additional join with 3rd table)
NOT EXISTS in the sub query with results from table A
Somehow it returns product names and BatchIds from Table B which already exists in Table A.
I need values from Table B only when values doesn’t exist in Table B.
How can I query this in the right way?
Please note there is no unique id to use instead for NOT IN, (StageID, BatchID, ProductName) combination is unique
My query is something like this (Sample):
SELECT DISTINCT Date, BatchID, ProductName, Change
FROM TableA
JOIN Table3 ON TableA.StageId = Table3.StageId
WHERE (conditions like Table3.StageName = 'Export' and TableA.Change IN (1,2) )
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT Date, BatchID, ProductName, 0 as Change
FROM TableB
JOIN Table3 ON TableB.BatchId = Table3.BatchId
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM TABLEA
    WHERE TableA.StageId = Table3.StageId
    AND (conditions like Table3.StageName = 'Export' and TableA.Change  NOT IN (1,2) )
)


Are your dates DMY or MDY? (It doesn't really make a difference in the solution, but I've assumed DMY, since it's October.)

Side note: SELECT ... from ... JOIN ... Where  - For the benefit of those who may have to read and maintain your code down the road, I suggest that you pick a coding style (perhaps one that matches others in your organization) and be consistent with formatting and capitalization.  Line breaks and indentation are also critical for code readability.

@TN I do follow, this is just a sample code

Before asking for additional help, I suggest that you fix the syntax errors in you posted sample query and qualify your column names (preferably with table aliases) to eliminate any potential "ambiguous column" errors. For the statement "I need values from Table B only when values doesn’t exist in Table B", did you mean "when the values don't exist in Table A joined with Table 3"? Also, please identify which columns should be used in the match logic? Lastly, are your dates DMY or MDY?

In case anyone else is still monitoring, here is a fiddle of the OP's latest data and query. (I had what I think was a workable answer that produced the posted results, but was awaiting clarification that never came.)

Your original question only provided sample data for and apparent results from Table A and Table B. Since you provided no information on Table 3 and the other two tables have no Id column (as referenced in your posted SQL), I have limited this answer to just the first two tables.
You can use a FULL OUTER JOIN together with COALESCE to select the original values in TableA when present, or to use the TableB values when no matching TableA row is present.
SELECT
    COALESCE(A.Date, B.Date) AS Date,
    COALESCE(A.BatchID, B.BatchID) AS BatchID,
    COALESCE(A.ProductName, B.ProductName) AS ProductName,
    COALESCE(A.Change, 0) AS Change
FROM TableA A
FULL OUTER JOIN TableB B
    ON B.Date = A.Date
    AND B.BatchID = A.BatchID
    AND B.ProductName = A.ProductName

This assumes that the combination of Date, BatchID, and ProductName values are unique in each source.
As suggested by Sabbha, you can also select all of TableA and UNION ALL those results with a TableB select that has a WHERE NOT EXISTS(...) condition.
SELECT A.Date, A.BatchID, A.ProductName, A.Change
FROM TableA A
UNION ALL
SELECT B.Date, B.BatchID, B.ProductName, 0 AS Change
FROM TableB B 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM TableA A
    WHERE A.Date = B.Date
    AND A.BatchID = B.BatchID
    AND A.ProductName = B.ProductName
)

See this db<>fiddle for a demo.

Table3 got column like Stage with values Export, Import and we need to get results for Stage Export alone.  Table A and Table B got an ID column representing a StageID. Table3 is the source of that with Stage details with ID that can be join with Table A and B. How do we achieve this result including Table3 which is essential to join to include these where conditions. How can we achieve this?

If you needed the answer to include Table3, it would have been best to include the specifics in the original question - sample data, the necessary columns to join to the other tables, and results that include the  associated logic and data from that table. The original vague description (and even your comment above) is just not enough to work with. The above answer shows general techniques to "Get all the result set from table A ... along with table B results ... not in table A". With the information given, I suspect that you just need to add the appropriate joins and conditions for table3.

Sorry I missed one key fact here that the Table A and Table B dont have a common BatchID and thats the reason Table 3 is so important. I have updated the original question. Please help

Hello You can also achive the desired output by using the Except operator in Sql Server:
select date, batchid, productname, change 
from TableA
union all
select date, batchid, productname, 0 as change 
from (
select date, batchid, productname 
from TableB
except 
select date, batchid, productname 
from TableA
)a;

Hope it helps.
